# Using XLOOKUP to be able to search for someone before a specific date Excel

Tags: excel, xlookup

Is there is a solution to be able to find the previous start date for a specific person?

When I use `=XLOOKUP(A3,N2:N10,I2:I10,,1)`, I can find the person who has the latest start date after `1/1,2000`

but cannot find the person who has the most previous start date before `1/1/2000`

I tried `=XLOOKUP(A3,N2:N10,I2:I10,,-1,1)` but returns `#N/A`

Do I need to change the formula or is there something in my format that needs to be fixed?

`Formula used:`
`=XLOOKUP(A3,N2:N10,I2:I10,,-1,1))`

`Desired Output = 10/3/1999`

`Output received`
`#N/A`

[image: XLOOPUP]

Comment: Does this work for you? `=XLOOKUP(A3,$N$2:$N$10,$I$2:$I$10,,-1,2)`

Comment: I tried it already and it returned #N/A

Comment: But that works on my end. [Check](https://imgur.com/gallery/BQwtM9e)

Comment: I am trying to look for the person before the start date of 1/1/2000. The one above that you gave me is correct for me.

Comment: yes I am able to find the next person after the start date but was wondering if possible to find person before start date

Comment: So can you post your expected output in the OP by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78117597/edit) the post

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. A "name of person" can be associated with more than one "start date"? And if there is more than one "start date", you want second to last date?

Comment: I wanted to be able to find a person or desired information based on the XLOOKUP by being able to look for a date prior to 1/1/2000 for example. It worked anything after the date but if I want to find something before, it is not possible, at least not by using XLOOKUP

Comment: Is the desired output is a date and not a name.

Comment: I am using the date to be able to return the name based on the start date prior to 1/1/2000. I had added some more information above

Comment: with the given date for the first one it does returns `Pam Beasley` using the above formula but what do you want for the second one?

Comment: =XLOOKUP(A3,N2:N10,I2:I10,,1,1) returns Angela Martin because it is the next latest date after 1/1/2000. however I am trying to return the name that is before 1/1/2000 which should return Pam Beasly but keep getting #N/A

Comment: No you are missing see my formula in the first comment as well as the screenshot i have posted this formula: `=XLOOKUP(A3,$N$2:$N$10,$I$2:$I$10,,-1,2)` which returns `Pam Beasly` for date : `10/3/1999` but i am not sure what do you want for the next date the one in cell `A4`

Comment: I keep getting #N/A when I use your formula =XLOOKUP(A3,N2:N10,I2:I10,,-1,2)

Comment: I have already added a link showing it is working, if you click on the word `Check` on top comments you may clearly see that.

Comment: Okay, so I got it to work on sheet.google.com. thank you for your assistance. However, I do not know why it is not working for Excel on my PC. Maybe I have to change the settings?